# Laravel DB design: how to model different types of similar entity

Tags: database, laravel, orm, eloquent, relational-database

First of all I have to mention that I am modernising our ERP system that is build in-house. It handles everything from purchasing of parts, sale orders, quotes and inventory to invoicing and statistical data. The system is web based and heavily dependent on ORM. EloquentORM will be used in the redesign.

My main question is about the data model of certain entities that are very similar. Currently three of most widely interconnected entities in the app are: **Orders, Products and Invoices**.

#### 1. Orders

In current DB design I have one big `orders` table in which there is a `order_type` attribute to distinct between different order types: Purchase orders, Sale orders, Quotes and Service orders. About 80% of fields are common to each order type and there are some specific fields for each order types. *Currently at ~15k records.*

#### 2. Products

Similarly I have one big `products` table with an attribute `product_type` to distinct between different product types: Finished products, Services, Assemblies and Parts. Again there is a fair % of fields that are common throughout all product types and some that are specific to different product type *Currently at ~7k records.*

#### 3. Invoices

Again one table `invoices` with `invoice_type` attribute to distinct between 4 invoice types: Issued invoices (for things we sell), Received invoices (for things we buy), Credit notes and Avans Invoices. More or less all invoice types use the same fields. *Currently at ~15k records.*

I am now trying to decide which is the optimal way for this kind of DB model. I see three options:

**1. Single Table Inheritance**

Leave as is, everything in the same table. It feels kind of awkward to always filter records like `where order_type = 'Sale order'` to display right orders in the right place in GUI... Also when doing sale and purchase analytics I need to include the same where condition to fetch right orders. Seems wrong!

**2. Class Table Inheritance**

Have a master tables `orders`, `products` and `invoices` with common set of fields between each of entity types and then `one-to-one` child relation tables for every different type of each entity: `sales_orders`, `purchase_orders`, `quote_orders`, `finished_products`, `reseller_products`, `part_products`, `assembly_products`, `received_invoices` and `issued_invoices` with FK in each of the child tables to master table... This seems like a good idea but handling that with ORM brings in a little more complexity...

In this method I have a questions which FK should be used around. For example each invoice can belong to one order. Received invoice will go with Purchase order and issued invoice will go with Sale order. Should the master `orders` table's PK be used as a FK in the master `invoices` table to relate these entities, or should the child `sale_orders` PK be used in the child `issued_invoices`?

**3. Concrete Table Inheritance**

Having completely separated tables for every type of each entity. This would avoid me having parent->child relationship between master table but would result in a lot of similar attributes in each table...

What would be the best approach? I am aiming at ease of use in EloquentORM and also speed and scalability for the future.

Comment: Just some hints (a full answer would take a lot of time): a) spend time to analyze your business logic. Your tables should reflect that, not the other way 'round. b) most ERP systems have different tables for vendors and customers, you might consider it (-> different tables for Purchase orders, Sale orders, same for invoices), because of different business processes. c) Having credit memos and invoices in the same table or not is a matter of taste, both have advantages. d) I would keep products in one table e) while having (1:1) inheritance looks nice in an ER-diagram, they are more ...

Comment: ...complex to handle. Putting them in 1 table is completely legal with respect to normalization. Generally speaking of course. If you have a type that needs 100 columns in 1% of the rows, you might consider a specialization table for just that. f) I'm living in a country with heavy regulations regarding accounting, so I might be overcautious, but spend some time with your accountant. And save every invoice / credit memo you send out (or receive) with all relevant data. Do not normalize e.g. adresses. Save the whole dataset as it was. You (or the one signing the financial report) rely on that.

Comment: @Solarflare thanks on your thoughts. It was a nice read. I am biased towards leaving one table for all products in our business process (finished products, assemblies, raw material, services) but separating invoices and orders tables... I want to keep vendors/customers in the same table as well because there are companies that serve as both and in this case feels better to have them in the same place.

Comment: I didn't meant to (necessarily) split up customers and vendors (the persons/entities) - it's easier in CRM management this way - but the other areas/tables for them, so e.g. have a table for `vendor invoices` and `customer invoices` (and same for orders). They usually behave differently enough to justify a new table (and is common practice), starting with the subtle thing that you get money/lose stock from customers invoices but have to pay money for vendor invoices. It will of course work either way (as you already know), but might be the thing you think "seems wrong" in your point 1).

Comment: @Solarflare The biggest problem I am facing now is that multiple table inheritance can not be cleanly implemented in Laravel's Eloquent ORM. There are solutions using `polymorphic` relations where master table hold 2-column key to the child tables with child_id and child_type columns, but this is a strange solution to me. When running plain SQLs I would have to write joins on two columns in order to get all data for purchase orders as there is no FK in the child table...

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained it clearly enough: I did not suggest multi-table inheritance (because it is complicated) - tables that have multiple types should have all fields in it, the fields for the unused types are left null. My suggestion was to have two completely independent tables for `customer invoices` and `vendor invoices` (same for orders). Although they have similar fields, they have nothing else to do with each other (e.g. they do not share a `primary key`, they are not childs of another table or each other, ...).